# Do all gases emit light if exposed to electron flow?

Tags: visible-light, electrons, gas

As we know neon or argon pipes do emit light (whatever range) if they are exposed to an electon current. 
So does potassium once evaporated in the common street lights.

Question: Does this apply to all gases or at least to homogenous gasess?
with homogenous I intend stuff like Cl2 but not CO2. So does any gas emit light, if it is hit by electrons or do some refuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by "electron flow", because you do not specify the electron energy. Is it a beam from an accelerator or a beam "inside" an accelerator, i.e., in an external electric field?

If the atoms/molecules are effectively excited, then there is some radiation due to deactivation of excitations.

If there is no electron flow, but the gas is at the temperature $T$, it may radiate a black body radiation or a less powerful radiation if it is "thin" enough.

Comment: The energy shall be arbitrary - so as much as you need. Just so that the atoms become excited. So they do all emit light - as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Though slightly different, I think you want to look at the [Frank-Hertz experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franck%E2%80%93Hertz_experiment).  If the electrons get enough energy to ionize the gas atoms, then you will have light.